# Android load resource file from library project

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

I have one android library project, there I need to load string from the strings.xml, how to do that. In normal android project we will use `getResources().getString(R.string.protocol)`. I need similar kind of way to access the resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access main project's resources from a library project.

You can access library project's resources the same way you access project's own resources from main project.

Comment: The whole idea of a library is that it holds your code, you should put your Strings inside the strings.xml of the library project then call them to your normal project, not the other way around. Doctoror is right.

Comment: I want to access library project resources only, inside same project